Vue2leaflet LPopup test if it is open
I am using Vue2Leaflet and my Markers have both a LPopup and LTooltip.
The LTooltip stay active (display on mouse hover) even when the LPopup is open, I would like to change this pattern to desactivate the Tooltip if the Popup is open.
The easy way to achieve this is to hide the Tooltip when Popup is open, but I didn't figure out how to detect if the Popup is open.
Seems there is no documentation about LPopup properties with an isOpen or opening/close related info, the only event seems to be for component ready, source :
https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.app/components/LPopup.html
Any workaround to solve my issue ?
Edit :
I tried to use isVisible() from test-utils : https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/isvisible.html on the popup to not display the Tooltip when a specific element of the Popup is visible, but it didn't work.

Inspecting the element locally is the way to go here IMO, see what's available on the element. Or looking for some similar Github issue.
